# TSQL for getting a list of all product groups and the products in the groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, hierarchy

Get a list of all product groups and the products in the groups from a MS SQL Server.
A product can exist in multiple product groups.

What i have so far, before i got lost :(

```
With CTE_Products As
(
    Select ProductGroupNo, Name, ParentProductGroupNo
    From [dbo].[ProductGroups]
    Where ParentProductGroupNo = 0

    Union All

    Select t.ProductGroupNo, t.Name, t.ParentProductGroupNo
    From [dbo].[ProductGroups] t
    Inner Join CTE_Products c On c.ProductGroupNo = t.ParentProductGroupNo
)

Select
    ProductGroupNo, ParentProductGroupNo
From
    CTE_Products
ORDER BY
    ProductGroupNo
```

## SQL Tables

[Products] - Table with products
-ProductNo (INT)
-Description (VARCHAR)

| ProductNo | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Desc1 |
| 2 | Desc2 |
| 3 | Desc3 |
| 4 | Desc4 |
| 5 | Desc5 |

[ProductGroups] - Table with product groups, if ParentProductGroupNo is 0, the it's the root.
-ProductGroupNo (INT)
-Name (VARCHAR)
-ParentProductGroupNo (INT)

| ProductGroupNo | Name | ParentProductGroupNo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Group1 | 0 |
| 2 | Group2 | 0 |
| 3 | Group3 | 1 |
| 4 | Group4 | 1 |
| 5 | Group5 | 2 |
| 6 | Group6 | 3 |
| 7 | Group7 | 5 |

[Products2Groups] - Table that ties products and groups. 1 product can exist in multiple groups.
-ProductNo (INT)
-ProductGroupNo (INT)

| ProductNo | ProductGroupNo |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 4 | 7 |

I'm looking for a Query (probably a CTE) that can give me a resultset that looks something like this:

| ProductNo | ProductGroup |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Group1 ***** Group3 |
| 2 | Group2 ***** Group5 |
| 2 | Group2 ***** Group5 ***** Group7 |
| 3 | Group2 |
| 4 | Group1 ***** Group3 ***** Group6 |
| 4 | Group1 ***** Group4 |
| 4 | Group2 ***** Group5 ***** Group7 |
| 5 |  |

Comment: *"so i won't post my rubbish attempts here, because the have lead me nowhere"* No, please do; show us what you've attempted and why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

With this query, no matter how many parent levels you have, you can get the exact answer you want:

```
WITH Hierarchy(ChildId, ChildName, ParentId, Parents)
AS
(
    SELECT [ProductGroupNo] Id, Name, [ParentProductGroupNo] ParentId, CAST('' AS VARCHAR(MAX))
        FROM [dbo].[ProductGroups] AS FirtGeneration
        WHERE [ParentProductGroupNo] = 0   
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NextGeneration.[ProductGroupNo], NextGeneration.Name, Parent.ChildId,
    CAST(CASE WHEN Parent.Parents = ''
        THEN(CAST(Parent.ChildName AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ' ***** ' + NextGeneration.Name)
        ELSE(Parent.Parents + ' ***** ' + CAST(NextGeneration.Name AS VARCHAR(MAX)))
    END AS VARCHAR(MAX))
        FROM [dbo].[ProductGroups] AS NextGeneration
        INNER JOIN Hierarchy AS Parent ON NextGeneration.[ParentProductGroupNo] = Parent.ChildId    
)
SELECT pg.ProductNo , Case when Len(Parents) = 0 then ChildName else Parents end ProductGroup
    FROM Hierarchy h
    inner join [dbo].[Products2Groups] pg
on pg.ProductGroupNo = h.ChildId
order by pg.ProductNo
```